# Sql query tuning/optimization

Tags: sql

For large amounts of data, it is taking a lot of time to execute.

Please help tune this query.

```
select * 
from 
    (select cs.sch, cs.cls, cs.std, d.date, d.count
     from 
         (select c.sch, c.cls, s.std
          from 
              (select distinct sch, cls from Data) c  --List of school/classes
          cross join 
              (select distinct std from Data) s --list of std
         ) cs  --every possible combination of school/classes and std
     left outer join 
         Data D on D.sch = cs.sch and D.cls = cs.cls and D.std = cs.std  --try and join to the original data
     group by 
         c.sch, c.cls, s.std, d.date, d.count) 
order by 
    cs.sch, cs.cls, 
    case 
       when (cs.std= 'Ax')
          then 1
       when (cs.std= 'Bo') 
          then 2
       when (cs.std= 'Ct') 
          then 3
       else null
    end
```

Thanks in advance

Magickk

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 2):

First, the query is generating a lot of rows (presumably) and so it is going to take time.

From what I can tell, the outer aggregation is not necessary.  At the very least, you have no aggregation functions which is suspicious.

```
select c.sch, c.cls, s.std, d.date, d.count
from (Select distinct sch, cls from Data
     ) c cross join    -- list of school/classes
     (select distinct std from Data
     ) s left join     -- list of std
     Data d
     on d.sch = cs.sch and d.cls = cs.cls and d.std = cs.std 
 order by cs.sch, cs.cls, 
          (case cs.std when 'Ax' then 1 when 'Bo' then 2 when 'Ct' else 3 end)
```

There is nothing you can do about the outer `order by`.  For the `select distinct` subqueries, you can create indexes on `data(sch, cls, std)` (the third column is for the `join`) and `data(std)`.

Answer (score 0):

DISTINCT is slowing down performance on big tables. Instead, a replacement for DISTINCT could be GROUP BY (wich in some scenarios is more rapid)

```
select * 
from 
(select cs.sch, cs.cls, cs.std, d.date, d.count
from 
(select c.sch, c.cls, s.std
 from 
(select sch, cls  from Data
group by sch, cls) c
cross join
(select std from Data
group by std) s) cs  --every possible combination of school/classes and std
 left outer join 
Data D on D.sch = cs.sch and D.cls = cs.cls and D.std = cs.std  --try and join to the original data
 group by 
     c.sch, c.cls, s.std, d.date, d.count) 
order by 
cs.sch, cs.cls, 
case 
   when (cs.std= 'Ax')
      then 1
   when (cs.std= 'Bo') 
      then 2
   when (cs.std= 'Ct')
```